# Automatically Translate Website based on URL Parameter using Google Translate

Tags: javascript, google-translate

I have a Website which currently is only in English. However, we have a Google Translate widget which will translate the website to any language selected by the user. Here's the small snippet:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement(
     {  pageLanguage: 'en', 
        layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
     }, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Now, I will be routing some traffic from Spanish speaking users to the site. Considering I know these **are** spanish speaking users, is there any call I can make on the code to Automatically translate the website to Spanish (i.e to **simulate** a user selecting a given option on the Translate)? I'd be using a specific URL param, such as for example **lang=spa**.

I tried browsing the code that gets inserted when the DIV is loaded, but it was just a very messy code to even look at.

Has anyone tried such thing, can you provide a code bit to follow up from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should help... just pass it into the URL like this:

https://support.google.com/translate/?hl=en#2643150

Comment: I feel so lazy for not finding that answer, which is on a public help page... 

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks! If for some reason that page moves, here's the important bit: 
"To do this, add #googtrans(en|TARGET_LANG_CODE) to the end of your site's URL"   e.g. http://www.stackoverflow.com/#googtrans(en|es) for spanish.

Comment: Looks like this link doesn't work, I tried finding the new url but couldn't. Could anyone help me please?